# python - opencv - detect color density/accumulation

Tags: python, opencv, color-detection

I already filtered the image for a specific color with a mask.
Is there a way to detect color accumulations of a specific density in the image.
I don't want to use HoughCirles because the parameters are to different from image to image.
However my goal is to count the circles in the image.
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: How would you define a "color accumulation" and it's associated "density"?

Comment: Somehow search if there is a high number of cohesive pixels in the same color range in a specific area